# Can I restore a backup made with Windows Server 2008 R2 in Windows Server 2012 R2?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

Can I make a backup on Windows Sever 2008 R2 (or 2008) with Windows Server Backup and restore it on Windows Server 2012 R2 (or 2012) with Windows Server Backup?

Comment: Needs more specificity. specifically, what you're backing up and what you're hoping to restore.

Comment: I have in mind restore a single common file (or various common files) and the posibility of restore the whole system.

Comment: What about a windows server backup file from Windows server 2008 R2 and restore it to windows server 2012 R2? Would this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this should be possible. I just tested this by backing up some files on 2008 R2 and restored them on a Server 2012 R2.

I haven't tested a `Full server`,`Bare metal recovery` or `System state` backup but that makes less sense anyways.