# Restoring Windows Server 2008 to 2012

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, backup-restoration, windows-server-backup

I am using Windows Server 2008 R2 and I am about to create a one time backup of a system drive (D: approx. 2TB - contains files and folders only), using the '**Windows Server Backup**' tool. I'm planning on saving this backup to an external HDD.

I will then rebuild the server and installing Windows Server 2012 R2.

Is it possible to restore the Windows Server 2008 R2 D drive backup to the newly built Windows Server 2012 R2 server? Is there anything I should be aware of before commencing this backup and restore?

Comment: If you only want to restore files on the drive, you're good (but don't need Windows Backup, I reckon). Restoring AD or system state won't work, because they're quite different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I restore a backup made with Windows Server 2008 R2 in Windows Server 2012 R2?](https://serverfault.com/questions/674351/can-i-restore-a-backup-made-with-windows-server-2008-r2-in-windows-server-2012-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about restoring files and folders then sure you will be able to restore them to the newly built Server 2012 R2 server, but you wont be able to restore system state. Why don't you do an in place upgrade instead?

Back everything up just in case things go wrong. If you do an in place upgrade all settings as well as applications and files and folders will be kept intact.